# Merging two generic list together

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model like this below.

```
public class ProcessData
{
    public Int32 ProcessDataId { get; set; }
    public string routenumber { get; set; }
    public string representative { get; set; }
    public string Ischecked { get; set; }
}
```

I populated this with data

A. `List<ProcessData> objMainData` - This has the main data say about 40 rows of data

B. `List<ProcessData> Manipulated data` - This has the main data with some modification. I changed data for 2 fields say 10 rows

I want to take B and merge it with A. I want A to have the full data with the modifications I made in B.  Is this possible?

Assuming this is my data below. How do I put this together?

```
        public class Collectiondata
            {
                public List<ProcessData> Objmaindata()
                {
                    List<ProcessData> objMain = new List<ProcessData>();
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId=1,routenumber="2001",representative="James",Ischecked=""});
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId=2,routenumber="2002",representative="John",Ischecked=""});
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId=3,routenumber="2003",representative="",Ischecked=""});
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId=4,routenumber="2004",representative="Bassey",Ischecked=""});
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId=5,routenumber="2005",representative="Adams",Ischecked="" });
                    return objMain;
                }

                public List<ProcessData> ManipulatedData()
                {
                    List<ProcessData> objMain = new List<ProcessData>();
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId = 1, routenumber = "3001", representative = "Sumbo", Ischecked = "Y" });
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId = 2, routenumber = "2002", representative = "Folabi", Ischecked = "Y" });
                    objMain.Add(new ProcessData() { ProcessDataId = 3, routenumber = "3035", representative = "James", Ischecked = "Y" });
                    return objMain;
                }


            }
```

Comment: Is `ProcessDataId` the unique identifier, and does the class have a Comparer?

Comment: Yes ProcessDataId is the unique identifier. It does not have a comparer

Comment: You can do this by creating a comparer (`IEqualityComparer<T>`) and using a linq `.Union()` clause. Give me a moment to test the code and I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate it. I have been trying to get this to work for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a comparer for your class that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`

```
public class ProcessDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProcessData>
{
    public bool Equals(ProcessData x, ProcessData y)
    {
        return x.ProcessDataId.Equals(y.ProcessDataId);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ProcessData obj)
    {
        return obj.ProcessDataId;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a linq `.Union()` to merge the 2 lists

```
var mergedList = manipulatedData.Union(objMainData, new ProcessDataComparer());
```

The merged list will include, first, the items from manipulatedData, then the items from `objMainData` which do not have a `ProcessDataId` matching one of the items in `manipulatedData`. Note that because they are now not in order, you may want to add an `.OrderBy(x => x.ProcessDataId)` clause to the end of the above query.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a test data. How do I now put this together. Never used this before.

Comment: What part are you not understanding?

Comment: How do I tie this to my data?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You have 2 `List<ProcessData>` collections - you just need to use the `.Union()` clause

Comment: Ok. I will play with it.

Comment: Based on your edit, you want `Collectiondata data = new Collectiondata(); List<ProcessData> manipulatedData = data.ManipulatedData(); List<ProcessData> objMainData = data.Objmaindata(); var mergedList = manipulatedData.Union(objMainData, new ProcessDataComparer());`

Comment: Actually the result is wrong. Maybe I should not have used the word merge. ManipulatedData should update all corresponding ProcessdataId in objmaindata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108584/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user2320476).

Comment: Thanks. Works like Magic